# include(helveticab.php): failed to open stream in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I tried to create pdf using FPDF
and I run the code in localserver.
It did not produced any errors.
I created a VM instance and Installed Xampp in it using Google Cloud Platform.
Then I moved all my local files to the server path `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.
After this when I try to run my php file it produced error like this.

```
    Warning: include(helveticab.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
    /opt/lampp/lib/php/fpdf.php on line 1145

    Warning: include(): Failed opening 'helveticab.php' for inclusion 
    (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/lib/php/fpdf.php on line 1145

    FPDF error: Could not include font definition file
```

What is the way to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

My FPDF font folder located in server at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Server/fpdf/font`.
So I added `define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/opt/lampp/htdocs/Server/fpdf/font');` in my php file.
This fixed my issue.